# Django streaming CSV stops prematurely

Tags: python, django, csv

I'm using the following code to stream a table and all its fields to a csv and then back to the user. It's more or less just the example from django's website.

```
        # CSV header
        header = [field.name for field in model._meta.fields]
        results = model.objects.all()

        # Generate a streaming output in case the file is large
        h = []
        h.append(header)
        rows = ([getattr(item, field) for field in header] for item in results)
        # Need to add the header to the front
        chained = itertools.chain(h, rows)

        pseduo_buffer = Echo()  # File like object that just returns value when write is called
        writer = csv.writer(pseduo_buffer)
        response = StreamingHttpResponse((writer.writerow(row) for row in chained), content_type="text/csv")
        filename = "{}_{}_{}.csv".format(app_name, model_name, date_str)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(filename)

        return response
```

The issue seems to be that for larger datasets, it will randomly stop the stream prior to actually finishing getting all the data from the table. The total file size is about 12MB or so, but it will stop streaming randomly from 500k to about 8MB.

I have only seen this in our production environment. I get the whole file when I do it in my development setup. It's all running in docker containers, so in theory it's the same setups in both instances. Not sure if there are other server related settings though that could be causing this?

Our devops guy did say he increased the load balancer timeouts, but I'm under the impression the streaming response shouldn't cause timeouts anyway because it's constantly sending data.

Is it possible it has to do with how the query is being executed, and it *thinks* it's done before it actually is (maybe poor query performance - a lot of joins, etc)?

Thanks everyone -